# RedirectRule relative urls to root folder

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

I have used Redirect rules to decode queries like

`user/34` to `user.php?id=34`

The problem is now using **relative urls** in user.php
`image.png` is now searched relatively to not existing folder user

what I want now is to attach `/` to each relative path.

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible: A relative path is made into an absolute path *in the browser*.

What arrives on server side is the absolute URL

```
http://example.com/user/34/images/image.png
```

The best fix would be to use absolute paths in your HTML markup:

```
<img src="/images/image.png">
```

You could also use the [`<base>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) tag, but I personally dislike the practice because of the confusion it tends to create. Using absolute paths from the start would be the cleanest way.

Comment: Currently I started to replace all relative paths be absolute once and for those I didn't do yet I use the <base>. I thought about redirect all requests to root except for existing directories. maybe somhow overload .htaccess then in the subfolders